# Decimal Format Value customisation issue

Tags: android, kotlin, math, rounding, decimalformat

I am using below code to convert 79.00538 to 79.00

```
val df = DecimalFormat("###.##")
df.roundingMode = RoundingMode.DOWN
val retrunValue= df.format(79.00538)
```

But it give me 79 instead of 79.00.

What might be the issue ?

Comment: With `#` zeros will be absent . you should use `0.00` or `#.00`

Comment: Great!!! Thanks.

Comment: I want -0.00 for -0.001054. So I think #.00 will not work ? so using "0.00"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DecimalFormat docs state](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat)

```
Symbol  Location    Localized?  Meaning
----------------------------------------------------------- 
0       Number      Yes         Digit 
#       Number      Yes         Digit, zero shows as absent
```

So `#` is a digit, but when it is zero, it will not be displayed.
Use `0` for places that you want displayed even when zero.

So I am assuming you wanted a format like this

```
val df = DecimalFormat("0.00")
```

Or possibly a format like this, if you want `0.1234` to display as `.12`

```
val df = DecimalFormat("#.00")
```

Comment: this displays okay but the value  -2.2386 is not displaying on graph. using "0.00"

Comment: @JaiminModi What do you mean by "graph"? `DecimalFormat("0.00")` works perfectly fine with negative numbers as well. So it must be something "graph" related.

Comment: yes its graph related. this is fine with DecimalFormat.